# VisualSVN - Changing branch while offline

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, offline, visualsvn-server

I have a remote VisualSVN Server. I created a branch and worked on it. I committed to server three times. Now I am offline but i want to switch trunk. Is it possible to change branch while offline?

Thanks,

Comment: always check out the whole project from SVN with all branches/trunk, so you have all code

Comment: thank you this is useful information

Comment: @magicandre1981 I'd recommend checking out a separate working copy just in case, but work on a WC that represents a particular branch or trunk.

Comment: @bahrep yes, this is what I always do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to switch a working copy to another branch, trunk or any other subtree when offline.